# Есть ли событие которое вызывается при изменении количества элементов в ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть ли событие которое вызывается при изменении количества элементов в ListBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) в качестве источника данных. Небольшой пример:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    int count = 0;

    BindingList<string> dataSource = new BindingList<string>();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listBox.DataSource = dataSource;
        dataSource.ListChanged += DataSource_ListChanged;
    }

    private void DataSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataSource.Add($"Count = {count + 1}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cудя по [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx) нет. Вы можете воспользоваться [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) в качестве источника данных для `ListBox` и подписаться на его событие изменения коллеции

Comment: ListBox "не понимает" ObservableCollection в качестве источника данных.